# Использование нескалярной VBA-функции в SQL запросе

Tags: access, vba, sql

У меня есть VBA-функция, возвращающая таблицу

```
Public Function GetNames() As ADODB.Recordset
```

Возможно ли использовать её в SQL запросах?

Например для обычной выборки: `SELECT * FROM GetNames()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю, что это возможно в Access.
Но можно поместить результат функции в таблицу, и затем выбирать из нее.

Comment: Да, как выяснилось, это, действительно, невозможно.